# What is Ruby doing with gsub here?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on converting code from Ruby to Node.js. I came across these lines at the end of a function and I'm curious what the original developers were trying to accomplish:

```
  url = url.gsub "member_id", "member_id__hashed"
  url = url.gsub member_id, member_id_hashed

  url
```

I'm assuming that `url` at the end is Ruby's equivalent to `return url;`
as for the lines with `gsub`, from what I've found online that's the wrong syntax, right? Shouldn't it be:

`url = url.gsub(var1, var2)`?

If it is correct, why are they calling it twice, once with quotes and once without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub` does a global substitute on a string. If I had to guess, the URL might be in the form of

`http://somewebsite.com?member_id=123`

If so, the code has the following effect:

```
url.gsub "member_id", "member_id__hashed"
# => "http://somewebsite.com?member_id__hashed=123"
```

Assuming `member_id = "123"`, and `member_id_hashed` is some hashed version of the id, then the second line would replace "123" with the hashed version.

```
url.gsub member_id, member_id_hashed
# => "http://somewebsite.com?member_id__hashed=abc"
```

So you're going from `http://somewebsite.com?member_id=123` to `http://somewebsite.com?member_id__hashed=abc`

Documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-gsub

Comment: It's worth noting that slapping `gsub` on a URL is probably wildly misguided. In this example if `123` coincidentally appeared somewhere else, anywhere else, in the URL then this would mangle that value as well. It's probably better to use the [URI module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) to manipulate parameters directly and do any re-writing in a more precise way.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm assuming that the url at the end is Ruby's equivalent to `return url;`

If that code is part of a method or block, indeed, the line `url` is the value returned by the method. This is because by default a [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) in Ruby [returns the value of the last expression that was evaluated](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) in the method. The keyword `return` can be used (as in many other languages) to produce an early return of a method, with or without a return value.

---

> that's the wrong syntax, right? shouldn't it be
>
> `url = url.gsub(var1, var2)`?

The arguments used to invoke a method in Ruby may stay in parentheses but they may, as well, be listed after the method name, without parentheses.

Both:

```
url = url.gsub var1, var2
```

and

```
url = url.gsub(var1, var2)
```

are correct and they produce the same result.

The convention in Ruby is to not put parentheses around method arguments but this is not always possible. One such case is when one of the arguments is a call of another method with arguments.
The parentheses are then used to make everything clear both for the interpreter and the readers of the code.

---

> If it is correct, why are they calling it twice, once with quotes and once without?

There are two calls of the same method, with different arguments:

```
url = url.gsub "member_id", "member_id__hashed"
```

The arguments of `url.gsub` are the literal strings `"member_id"` and `"member_id__hashed"`.

```
url = url.gsub member_id, member_id_hashed
```

This time the arguments are the variables `member_id` and `member_id_hashed`.

This works the same in JavaScript and many other languages that use double quotes to enclose the string literals.

---

[`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) is a method of class [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html) that does *search & replace* in a string and returns a new string. It's name is short of "global substitute" (it replaces all occurrences). To replace only the first occurrence use [`String#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-sub).